# How do I display table row data and change icon when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the arrow toggle to display the row data when clicked. At the same time, I'd like the arrow to turn from right to down. This would all reverse when clicked again to hide the row and change the arrow back. I know the code is plain html, I'll clean it up later for sure. My knowledge with scripts and more advanced CSS, is very limited. Thank you for any assistance.

I tried searching for the past few days, but have had minimal luck. I may be asking the question wrong when searching.

My HTML below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Breaking News</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#EEEEEE" link="0000FF" vlink="0000FF" alink="0000FF">

<table width="400" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000000" width="" colspan="7"><span style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><b>Breaking News</b></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><b>Date</b></span></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><b>Subject</b></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 10:00a</span></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #000000; cursor: pointer;">&#9654;</span> <a href="#">Article Name Here</a></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 9:00a</span></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #000000; cursor: pointer;">&#9660;</span> <a href="#">Article Name Here</span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="" colspan="2">
<span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">

Content I'd like displayed when the arrow is clicked<br>

</span>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 8:00a</span></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #000000; cursor: pointer;">&#9654;</span> <a href="#">Article Name Here</a></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to display row content when the arrow is clicked and have the arrow point down instead of right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the feature you wanted perfectly. Click on the first and the last icons to see the result. The required CSS and JS are given below with necessary comments:

```js
// getting all the spans
var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');

// Looping through the spans
for (i = 0; i < span.length; i++){
    // Checking if the span has the text content of '▶'
    if(span[i].textContent === '▶'){
        span[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            // For changing the arrow
            this.classList.toggle('arrow');
            // For displaying and hiding the content
            this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.classList.toggle('display-none');
        })
    }
}
```

```css
/*Adding a class for toggling the arrow rotation */
.arrow{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    display: inline-block;
}

/*Adding a class for toggling the show-hide content */
.display-none{
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Breaking News</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#EEEEEE" link="0000FF" vlink="0000FF" alink="0000FF">

<table width="400" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000000" width="" colspan="7"><span style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><b>Breaking News</b></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><b>Date</b></span></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><b>Subject</b></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 10:00a</span></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #000000; cursor: pointer;">&#9654;</span> <a href="#">Article Name Here</a></span></td>
</tr><tr style="display: none;">
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="" colspan="2">
<span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">

Content I'd like displayed when the arrow is clicked<br>

</span>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 9:00a</span></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #000000; cursor: pointer;">&#9660;</span> <a href="#">Article Name Here</span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="" colspan="2">
<span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">

Content I'd like displayed when the arrow is clicked<br>

</span>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 8:00a</span></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #000000; cursor: pointer;">&#9654;</span> <a href="#">Article Name Here</a></span></td>
</tr><tr style="display: none;">
<td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="" colspan="2">
<span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">

Content I'd like displayed when the arrow is clicked<br>

</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>

</body>

</html>
```

For the additional Requirement (Clicking on one button will open all the content at once and toggle):

You simply need to assign a class named `all-open` to that button and it will do it. But remember: You can only assign it to one button. And then add the newly added JS (also marked with comment).

```js
// getting all the spans
var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');

// Looping through the spans
for (i = 0; i < span.length; i++){
    // Checking if the span has the text content of '▶'
    if(span[i].textContent === '▶'){
        span[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            // For changing the arrow
            this.classList.toggle('arrow');
            // For displaying and hiding the content
            this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.classList.toggle('display-none');
        })
    }
}


// For opening all the content at once
document.querySelector('.all-open').addEventListener('click', function(){

    for (i = 0; i < span.length; i++){
        // Checking if the span has the text content of '▶'
        if(span[i].textContent === '▶'){
            // For changing the arrow
            span[i].classList.toggle('arrow');                    

            // For displaying and hiding the content
            span[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.classList.toggle('display-none');                
        }
    }
})
```

```css
/*Adding a class for toggling the arrow rotation */
.arrow{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    display: inline-block;
}

/*Adding a class for toggling the show-hide content */
.display-none{
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#EEEEEE" link="0000FF" vlink="0000FF" alink="0000FF">

    <table width="400" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000000" width="" colspan="7"><span style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><b>Breaking News</b></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><b>Date</b></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><b>Subject</b></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 10:00a</span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #000000; cursor: pointer;">&#9654;</span> <a href="#">Article Name Here</a></span></td>
    </tr><tr style="display: none;">
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="" colspan="2">
    <span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
    
    Content I'd like displayed when the arrow is clicked<br>
    
    </span>
    </td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 9:00a</span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #000000; cursor: pointer;">&#9654;</span> <a href="#">Article Name Here</span></td>
    </tr><tr style="display: none;">
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="" colspan="2">
    <span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
    
    Content I'd like displayed when the arrow is clicked<br>
    
    </span>
    </td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 8:00a</span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #000000; cursor: pointer;">&#9654;</span> <a href="#">Article Name Here</a></span></td>
    </tr><tr style="display: none;">
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="" colspan="2">
    <span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
    
    Content I'd like displayed when the arrow is clicked<br>
    
    </span>
    </td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Aug 22, 2023 / 9:00a</span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width=""><span style="color: #0000FF; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #04f8f8; cursor: pointer;" class="all-open">&#9654;</span> <a href="#">All Open</span></td>
    </tr><tr style="display: none;">
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="" colspan="2">
    <span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
    
    Content I'd like displayed when the arrow is clicked<br>
    
    </span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are most welcome. Glad to know it helped :)

Comment: I need some more points to give it an up, I'll make sure to do that when I can!

Comment: These codes are written for dynamic content which means if you follow the current structure and add more rows it will perfectly work. But if you find any issue you can update it here :)

Comment: I have it running with about six rows now, it is absolutely perfect. Is it possible to have a link that allows you to open all at once? If not, no big deal. Thank you so much again for your assistance.

Comment: When the link will be clicked and all table content will be open, in that case, do you want to change the rotation of all the buttons as well? Or button rotation is not necessary ?

Comment: Ohh wow, I'd love all arrows to turn if possible. Visually I'm thinking of an arrow next to Subject that would be the toggle for everything below. Of course, everything else works the way it currently does if that one isn't touched. If this is way to intensive, please disregard.

Comment: The new feature is added. I updated the answer. Please check it :)

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough, this is incredible to me. I'm a front end developer, so this just blows me away, thank you again for everything. I really hope it helps others in the future as well!

Comment: Glad to know we are on the same field :) You are most welcome. Happy coding :)

Comment: Just for anyone who may use this, you can't use the arrow icon (&#9654;) when the page is published, I switched to a plus sign (+), works perfect! Oddly it works fine when loaded on your PC, but I guess it doesn't see the arrow due to the &#9654; compared to ▶... maybe I missed something, but that's what happened and how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div to contain all the elements you want to hide/show and give it an ID.

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <--! content you want to hide/show -->
</div>
```

In JS you can toggle this div's visibility via

```js
// hide
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";

// show
document.getElementbyId("myDIV").style.display = "block";
```

```js
// Call this function on button press to toggle div
function myFunction() 
{
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") 
  {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

[Reference for toggling elements](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)

To rotate an arrow you can use css transforms. Reference [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)

```css
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I get back home, I thought the DIVs would break the <tr> elements even if hidden.

Answer (score 0):

1-i sugggest you to use [font awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4/)  instead of emoji codes.

2-use onclick event. `<span onclick="toggleArrow()"> </span>`
for font awesome `<i onclick="toggleArrow()" class="fa-solid fa-square-chevron-right"></i>`

3-define id `<i id="arrow" onclick="toggleArrow()" class="fa-solid fa-square-chevron-right"></i>`

4-define your function in script tag end of body `

function toggleArrow(){
       ...
    }
`

5-you can change the icons by changing class of   tag

6-access to class of elements using `document.getElementById("arrow").classList`

7-deleting class using `document.getElementById("arrow").classList.remove()`

8-add class using `document.getElementById("arrow").classList.add("anyClassName")`

9-use if condition in your function to change the class

Comment: Font Awesome is great, I was mainly trying to stray away from using another service just in case something ever happened to them. BTW, if your username is referring to "The Boys" that's awesome!

Comment: yeah it refers to "boys". tnx. its good to not using prebuild modules or codes but seeing codes can be very helpful for learning. even if u r new  see codes a lot.